# MediaRecorder do not start with code -38

Tags: android, sockets, video-streaming

I am trying to write video to socket (with ParcelFileDescriptor). But when calling mediaPlayer.start() method - an IllegalStateException occurs with this message - "E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38".

Code for file descriptor (Socket is 100% properly connected by the time programm calls it):

```
public ParcelFileDescriptor getFileDescriptorToSocket() {
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
    }
```

Preparing media recorder:

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        // mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurface.getHolder().getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        //mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MainActivity.socketClient.getFileDescriptorToSocket().getFileDescriptor());

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {

            // TODO Delete test code
            Log.d(TAG, "Error during MediaRecorder preparing:  " + ise.getMessage());
            ise.printStackTrace();

            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            // TODO Delete test code
            Log.d(TAG, "Error during MediaRecorder preparing:  " + ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();

            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
```

return true;
    }

and call for start recording:

```
private void startRecording() {
        if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {

            // TODO Delete test code
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting recording process");

            finish();
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mediaRecorder.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Delete test code
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error in recording thread:  " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            recordingStatus = true;
        }
    }
```

I should note that when i disable start recording method - camera works fine - i can properly see camera preview surface.

Comment: I wonder why this is not answered, Did you find the solution by any chance?

Comment: The times passed since i posted this question)) I can't remember how, but i solved this - will try to find code)

Comment: That will be highly appreciated. I do not seem to grasp this. I even thought the client does not support the video format but even if the client is the same android phone,no luck.

Comment: its has been 4 years and it seems that the question is still relevant, can you please post the solution?